# Swift: Recursively setting computed property

Tags: swift

In Swift 3, I am declaring a computed property that will always return a non-nil positive value. The property is stored in UserDefaults (which means that it will be nil the first time the app runs):

```
var notificationInterval: TimeInterval {
    get {
        let interval = UserDefaults(suiteName: "groupName")?.double(forKey: "notificationInterval") as TimeInterval?

        if interval == nil || interval! <= 0 {
            notificationInterval = defaultInterval
            return notificationInterval
        } else {
            return interval!
        }
    }

    set {
        UserDefaults(suiteName: "groupName")?.set(newValue, forKey: "notificationInterval")
    }
}
```

On line 6 and 7:

```
notificationInterval = defaultInterval
return notificationInterval
```

I get the following error:

```
Attempting to access 'notificationInterval' within its own getter.
```

I understand the error, but how would I design this differently? I am accessing the property "within its own getter" on purpose.

Comment: Avoid explicitly checking for `nil` then force unwrapping. Just use conditional binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the check for correct data in the setter, something like

```
var notificationInterval: TimeInterval {
    get {
        if let interval = UserDefaults(suiteName: "groupName")?.double(forKey: "notificationInterval") as? TimeInterval {
                return interval
        }  else {
            return defaultInterval
        }
    }

    set {
        if let interval = newValue, interval <= 0 {
            UserDefaults(suiteName: "groupName")?.set(defaultInterval , forKey: "notificationInterval")
        } else {
            UserDefaults(suiteName: "groupName")?.set(newValue, forKey: "notificationInterval")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the warning, just replace

```
notificationInterval = defaultInterval
return notificationInterval
```

with

```
return defaultInterval
```

> ... which means that it will be nil the first time the app runs

You can use the [`register`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1417065-register) function to register your default value so that it is available from `UserDefaults` the first time the program is run.

```
let dict: [String: Any] = ["notificationInterval": 5.0]
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: dict)

let interval = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "notificationInterval")
// interval = 5
```